# Preventing the end user from getting multiple copies of the same e-mail

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange-2010

I have the following scenario below and I can't seem to come up with a clean solution.

Employee A left the company and has mail forwarded to Supervisor A via Exchange Delivery Forwarding.
Supervisor A has gone on vacation and has his mail forwarded via Inbox Rule to Supervisor B.

An e-mail comes in that is addressed to Employee A, Supervisor A, and Supervisor B. The end result is that Supervisor B gets 3 copies of the same e-mail.

Is there a way to prevent that from occurring? I can't seem to create a rule that would allow the copy that keep only the copy that was sent to Supervisor B. I have a feeling that this cannot be accomplished because it's 3 different e-mails and each one is handled as it comes into the server.

Comment: This can't be resolved unless you can modify inbox rule yourself.  The simple solution is forward the male of Employee A to both Supervisors and create an exception to the Supervisor's Inbox Rule to NOT forward email to Employee A

Comment: But wouldn't that still create two copies of the mail message in Supervisor B's inbox? The message is still sent to all three people, there's just one less daily chain in the messages.

Comment: If Supervisor A is no longer forwarding the email from Employee A your only dealing with 2 copies.  Your real solution is to stop forwarding emails to Employee A, leave an away message, telling contacts who to actually contact.  Employee B can also create a rule to move any email address to Employee A and use an add-on to remove duplicate emails.